# reshape data and coerce missing to zero

Tags: r, casting, reshape2, melt

EDIT:
The original dataset can be found here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4FnlzCZUFqWcHVVd3RXQnQwQzQ/view?usp=sharing)

I have a matrix like:

```
data <- matrix(c("a","1","10",
             "b","1","20",
             "c","1","30",
             "a","2","10",
             "b","2","20",
             "a","3","10",
             "c","3","20"),
             ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

I would like to reshape as a dataframe coercing the missing values to zero:

```
data <- matrix(c("a","1","10",
             "b","1","20",
             "c","1","30",
             "a","2","10",
             "b","2","20",
             "c","2","0",
             "a","3","10",
             "b","3","0",
             "c","3","20"),
             ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

How can I do it with the reshape package?
Thaks

Comment: Why are you using a `matrix`?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete` from tidyr, after converting your data a little:

```
library(tidyr)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$V3 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$V3))
complete(data, V1, V2, fill = list(V3 = 0))
```

Comment: on my data it says: Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) : 
  attempt to set index 0/0 in SET_STRING_ELT. In my true dataset V3 is (int). does it affect it somehow?

Comment: I fear there's something wrong with the data I shared, but I cant understand what. here's the original data: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4FnlzCZUFqWcHVVd3RXQnQwQzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: from your data, I think you want `complete(data, label, count, fill = list(unique_elements = 0))` ?

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr` better but if you want use `reshape` you can

```
library(reshape2)

data2=dcast(data = as.data.frame(data),V1~V2)
data3=melt( data2,measure.vars=colnames(data2)[-1])
data3[is.na(data3)]="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you are handling something like a multivariate time series. Therefore I would suggest using a proper time series object.

```
library(zoo)
res=read.zoo(data.frame(data,stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
         split=1,
         index.column=2,
         FUN=as.numeric)
coredata(res)=as.numeric(coredata(res))
coredata(res)[is.na(res)]=0
```

This gives

```
res
#  a  b  c 
#1 10 20 30
#2 10 20 0 
#3 10 0  20
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it wrong by having a matrix with multiple classes.

First I would convert to a `data.frame` or to a `data.table` and then convert all the column to the proper type. Something like

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
# Convert to data.table
DT <- as.data.table(data) 

# Convert to correct column types
for(j in names(DT)) set(DT, j = j, value = type.convert(DT[[j]]))
```

Then we can expand rows using `data.table::CJ` and assign zeroes to `NA` values

```
## Cross join all column except the third
DT <- DT[do.call(CJ, c(unique = TRUE, DT[, -3, with = FALSE])), on = names(DT)[-3]]

## Or if you want only to operate on these two columns you can alternatively do
# DT <- DT[CJ(V1, V2, unique = TRUE), on = c("V1", "V2")]

## Fill with zeroes
DT[is.na(V3), V3 := 0]
DT
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  a  1 10
# 2:  a  2 10
# 3:  a  3 10
# 4:  b  1 20
# 5:  b  2 20
# 6:  b  3  0
# 7:  c  1 30
# 8:  c  2  0
# 9:  c  3 20
```

Comment: I fear there's something wrong with the data I shared, but I cant understand what. here's the original data: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4FnlzCZUFqWcHVVd3RXQnQwQzQ/view?usp=sharing)